# SAS date formatting hours / minutes / seconds

Tags: datetime, sas, string-formatting

Because my time data has some messy characters in it ( *, #, char, etc) I'm inputting the data in `best.32` format and then using compress to remove the irrelevant char - `time_1 = compress(Tim_original,'*#','l');`

However, my data takes the form of `mm:ss` and `hh:mm:ss` and for some reason when I use `time_1=input(time_1,time8.)` to convert from the string to a num, it makes my mm into hours...! How do I covert my string to time/minutes and not have the minutes turned into hours with ":00" added at the end?

Comment: please show sample data, so that someone can help you.

Comment: Try checking the length of your compressed time string (`length(timestring)<=5`) or counting the number of colons (:) (`countc(timestring,':')=1`).  For those cases prepend `00:` to `timestring` prior to using `input`

Answer (score 2):

If your text only has one `:` then the informat `TIME` will take that to mean `hh:mm` and not `mm:ss`.  You could just test your string and divide the result of the INPUT() function call by 60 to convert it.

```
data test;
  input @1 timestr $8. ;
  time1=input(timestr,time8.);
  time2=input(timestr,time8.);
  if countw(timestr,':') < 3 then time2=time2/60 ;
  format time1 time2 time8.;
cards;
12:34
0:12:34
;
```